# asp.net budle.config not including new css files

Tags: css, asp.net, bundle

I have problem that in my budle.config file I have added some css files with correct path & I rebuild the solution also but it is not including any new files in page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.0">
  <styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
    <include path="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/style.css" />
    <include path="~/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.css" />
  </styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

Here my original base style name is style.css & some other files for fonts but it is not working. I have seen many solutions which says it doesn't support .min.css files so I removed that as well but still didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. use **BundleConfig** class and **RegisterBundles** method :

   ```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Web;
       using System.Web.Optimization;

       namespace Core
       {
           public class BundleConfig
           {            
               public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
               {

                   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/css/bootstrap.css",
                       "~/Content/css/style.css",
                       "~/Content/css/font-awesome.css"                                       
                   ));
               }
           }
       }
   ```
2. in **head** of your **_Layout.cshtml** write:

   ```
    <head>
           @System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    </head>
   ```
3. call **RegisterBundles** in **Application_Start()** :

   ```
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
   ```